# How to display data to specific domain names who have a subdomain pointing to one central location

Tags: apache, http, subdomain

im not sure what this is called and i'll try to be as clear as possible. I have a server lets called it ServerA and 3 separate domains hosted on 3 separate ips. Then i create subdomains on each of the domains and have the cname point to ServerA. When you visit subdomain.domain1.com How can I have information specific for that domain show up and have completely different information show up for subdomain.domain2 and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but I'll try to point you in the right direction.

You want CNAME records for specific subdomains to point to one server and show different content depending on which domain is visited? This can be managed through your web server. If you're using Apache you'll want to look into VirtualHosts. Other web servers will have something similar that you can configure.